# how to close command prompt in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, command-prompt

i cant get my command prompt to close or kill its self, any ideas

```
Dim testsfse As Process
Private Sub FlatButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatButton1.Click

    testsfse = Process.Start("cmd", String.Format("/k {0} & {1}", "cd C:\Users\zeltron\Desktop\Pro Sour\Crypto Miners\nightminer-master", "python nightminer.py -o stratum+tcp://stratum.f2pool.com:3333 -u zeltron1.limeminer -p 123"))

End Sub


Private Sub FlatButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatButton2.Click

    testsfse.Kill()
    testsfse.Close()

End Sub
```

this is not working i want it to close when i click flatbutton2.
all it does is crash and give me an error

Additional information: No process is associated with this object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think it might be because of the .Close() Being after the .Kill() since kill forcible closes it, the close after might be having a problem since the process not longer exists since its been killed.

You could always use this, although it will close every open instance of CMD if no better solution is found of whats causing the problem.

```
    For Each p As Process In Process.GetProcesses
        If p.ProcessName = "cmd" Then
            Try
                p.Kill()
            Catch ex As exception
                Continue For
            End Try
        End If
    Next
```

when i used the same code in what you have written in a similar test, only changing the CMD command to open task manager instead, it worked fine for me without any errors.